# Build range-slider using Stencil

Tags: typescript, slider, range, stenciljs, stencil-component

I want to build a **range-slider using stencil**.

Above the range slider is an `h1` which should give back the **correct value of the slider**.

I use a **Listen-Event**, which listens if the `range-slider` was clicked (I also tried change, but that didn't work). If it is clicked, `handleChangeEvent` is executed. In this method I have my variable `meinSlider` which is previously assigned to `input type="range"`. On this variable, I use `addEventListener`, which listens for "change" and then I use `document.querySelector` and select my `span` element, which should give the correct number and assign it to the value of the range-slider:

```js
document.querySelector(".regler-wertung span").innerHTML = this.value;
```

However, it doesn't work and if I use a `console.log` it gives back `null`.
**I guess I can't access the HTML-Element**.

Besides, I have an Error:

> TypeError: **Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null** at regler.changeEvent, at regler.handleChangeEvent, at HTMLElement.listenMeta.eventDisabled.plt.domApi.$addEventListener.ev

I'm anything else but a pro and don't have any experience with Stencil.

I'm very thankful for any help.

Not sure, if this matters, but I'm also using **Electron**, because it's a Desktop-App.

Heres my .tsx:

```
import { Component, Prop, Listen, } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
    tag: 'regler-wertung',
    styleUrl: 'regler.css',
    shadow: false
})
export class regler {
    @Prop() regler: string;
    @Prop() value: number;

    meinSlider=document.querySelector('#myRange')

    @Listen ('click', {capture: true})
    handleChangeEvent(){
      this.meinSlider.addEventListener("change", function(){ 
        document.querySelector(".regler-wertung span").innerHTML = this.value; 
        })
      }
    render() {
     return (
        <div>
            <h1 class="regler-wertung">gewichtete Punkte von 0-10: {this.regler} <span>0</span></h1>
            <input type="range" id="myRange" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="10" ></input>
        </div>
          )
        }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368457/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
import { Component, Prop, Listen, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
    tag: 'regler-wertung',
    styleUrl: 'regler.css',
    shadow: false
})
export class regler {
    @Prop() regler: string = "defaultRegler";
    @Prop() value: number = 50;

    meinSlider!: HTMLInputElement; // Added for this error Cannot read property 'addEventListener'

    @Listen('click', { capture: true })
    handleChangeEvent() {
        this.meinSlider.addEventListener("change", function () {
            // not required now
            // document.querySelector(".regler-wertung span").innerHTML = this.value;
        })
    }

    updateValue(event: Event) {
        this.value = parseInt((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 class="regler-wertung">gewichtete Punkte von 0-10: {this.regler} <span>{this.value}</span></h1>
                <input type="range" id="myRange" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="10" onChange={this.updateValue} ref={ele => this.meinSlider = ele as HTMLInputElement}></input>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**For updating the value:**
I have added `updateValue` method (called on **onChange** event) where I am updating the prop.

**For addEventListener of null error:** I have updated `meinSlider` also added updating this variable in input tag have a look.